# Adding rules to a Json parser

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am trying to design a Json parser that takes a bunch of rules (eg. can be provided in a config file), which define how to parse a given Json file.
It would allow for a generic parser that can be used by different systems in different ways.

Rules could for instance impose a Json syntax/layout.
Rules could also be used by the parser to create a bunch of objects and populate them based on Json inputs.

So far, I came up with a very nasty Json parser that hardcode the Json layout and populate several objects. It is not workable as is.

Here is a diagram to clarify what I am trying to do:

[image]

Any input/example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Sela please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.